# I want to change the color of the Sharepoint site to another custom color

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to change the color of the Sharepoint site to another custom color or put a background image

Comment: Have you tried googling this? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-look-of-your-sharepoint-site-06bbadc3-6b04-4a60-9d14-894f6a170818

Comment: How is this a programming question??

Answer (score 0):

We can use PnP PowerShell to achieve it.

**Example**:

```
Set-PnPTheme -ColorPaletteUrl _catalogs/theme/15/company.spcolor -BackgroundImageUrl 'style library/background.png'
```

**Source Code**: [Set SharePoint Theme](https://github.com/ldsouza/Pnp-SharePoint-Branding/tree/master/Set%20SharePoint%20Theme)

More information: [SharePoint site theming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview)